# php date_parse_from_format() does not recognise difference between y and Y

Tags: php, validation, date, laravel

Been working with the Laravel validator and I've noticed an odd problem with validating dates.

Laravel date_format relies on the php date_parse_from_format method. However this method does not seem to recognise the difference between y and Y when you set the format to d/m/Y. So if you pass in 01/01/15 or 01/01/2015 both parse with no errors. You'd expect the former to error, or at least I would.

If you change the format to d/m/y it works as expected. That is 01/01/15 passes and 01/01/2015 fails.

I'd be interested to know if anyone else has any thoughts on this and whether I've missed something obvious. This may have an impact on both PHP and Laravel.

Note I'm using php 5.6.16 and my output is as follows...

```
string 'd/m/Y' (length=5)
string '01/01/15' (length=8)

array (size=12)
  'year' => int 15
  'month' => int 1
  'day' => int 1
  'hour' => boolean false
  'minute' => boolean false
  'second' => boolean false
  'fraction' => boolean false
  'warning_count' => int 0
  'warnings' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'error_count' => int 0
  'errors' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'is_localtime' => boolean false

string 'd/m/Y' (length=5)
string '01/01/2015' (length=10)

array (size=12)
  'year' => int 2015
  'month' => int 1
  'day' => int 1
  'hour' => boolean false
  'minute' => boolean false
  'second' => boolean false
  'fraction' => boolean false
  'warning_count' => int 0
  'warnings' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'error_count' => int 0
  'errors' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'is_localtime' => boolean false

string 'd/m/y' (length=5)
string '01/01/15' (length=8)

array (size=12)
  'year' => int 2015
  'month' => int 1
  'day' => int 1
  'hour' => boolean false
  'minute' => boolean false
  'second' => boolean false
  'fraction' => boolean false
  'warning_count' => int 0
  'warnings' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'error_count' => int 0
  'errors' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'is_localtime' => boolean false

string 'd/m/y' (length=5)
string '01/01/2015' (length=10)

array (size=12)
  'year' => int 2020
  'month' => int 1
  'day' => int 1
  'hour' => boolean false
  'minute' => boolean false
  'second' => boolean false
  'fraction' => boolean false
  'warning_count' => int 0
  'warnings' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'error_count' => int 1
  'errors' => 
    array (size=1)
      8 => string 'Trailing data' (length=13)
  'is_localtime' => boolean false
```

**Example code for output data is...**

```
$format = 'd/m/Y';
var_dump($format);
$date = '01/01/15';
var_dump($date);
var_dump(date_parse_from_format($format, $date));

$format = 'd/m/Y';
var_dump($format);
$date = '01/01/2015';
var_dump($date);
var_dump(date_parse_from_format($format, $date));

etc...
```

Comment: How are you actually parsing out your date? Can you show us some code?

Comment: Probably because `15`, i.e. `15AD` is a valid year which can be assumed to be `0015`.

Comment: Added some code. I assume also that it relates to 15 AD but Y implies yyyy. So surely it should not parse on that bases. It expects four digits?

Comment: Nope, `Y` implies that it is a full date. For all that matters, the function will split up the fragments of the date and then try to convert it to integer. `string('15')` will successfully convert to `int(15)`

Comment: So then date_parse_from_format is not the correct method to use if you want to check a date is exactly 'dd/mm/yyyy' then?

Comment: See my edited answer below

Comment: Ok maybe there are some crossed wires here and I should explain myself better. I'm very sorry. In my instance the date string must match dd/mm/yyyy. So the year part of the string must have four digits. If a two digit year gets through the wrong date may be put into the database. E.g. 01/01/15 will create in the db 01/01/0015. So what I think we're saying here is that neither date_parse_from_format nor createFromFormat are suitable methods to check for correct year length. At least on their own.

Comment: Nop, `DateTime::createFromFormat` default behaviour will work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

This is intended behaviour, not a bug.

15 will be interpreted as 0015 A.D., then, `d/m/Y` will be able to sucessfully parse it.

Another possible outcome:

```
$date3 = date_parse_from_format('d/m/y', '01/01/2015');
var_dump($date3);
```

This will generate:

```
array(12) {
  ["year"]=>
  int(2020)
  ["month"]=>
  int(1)
  ["day"]=>
  int(1)
  ["hour"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["minute"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["second"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["fraction"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["warnings"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["error_count"]=>
  int(1)
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    [8]=>
    string(13) "Trailing data"
  }
  ["is_localtime"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Notice the `errors` index. It will sucessfully interpret `01/01/20` as Jan, 1st 2020 and will generate an error that it found trailing data.

## Edit

When you switch to the OO API `DateTime::createFromFormat` the default behaviour changes and **work as you expect**:

```
$date3 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', '01/01/2015');
var_dump($date3); // will yield FALSE, as it does not recognize the intput
```

As of PHP 5.3.9, we can use the `+` flag that will behave just like `date_parse_from_format`:

```
$date3 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y+', '01/01/2015');
var_dump($date3); // will yield a DateTime object
```

The you can get the generated errors with `DateTime::getLastErrors()`.

See the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Comment: I tested 'd/m/y' and got the expected result, see my output. The issue here for me is the documentation within php says Y should match four digits. So only 0015 should match,  while 15 should error. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php